# Table dimension Latex

Tags: tables

I have been trying to have the adequate dimension of this table, I don't know how to solve that with latex program. Please help with explication.

This is my program :

```
\begin{table}

\caption{Essai de perméabilité sous charge constante}
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}XXXXXXX}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Paramèmtres du perméamètre type \textit{PROCTOR}}  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{}\\

\multicolumn{4}{c}{ Epaisseur $116.30 mm$ } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Surface $= 8 107.32 $ }\\

\multicolumn{4}{c}{ Volume $942 881.28 mm^3$} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Diamètres $= 101.30mm$}\\

\midrule Paramètre & Unité & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Gradient hydraulique N. 1} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Gradient hydraulique N. 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Gradient hydraulique N. 3}\\

\midrule Déférence de hauteur ($\delta H$) & $(mm)$ & $\delta H_1$ & $820$ &$ \delta H_2$& $965$  &$ \delta H_3$ & $1055$ \\

\midrule Masse bécher et eau ($m_{tot}$) & $(g)$ &$ m_{tot_1}$ & 580.6 &$ m_{tot_2}$ & 449.6  &$ m_{tot_3}$& $459.7$ \\

\midrule Masse bécher ($m_e$) & $(g)$ &\multicolumn{6}{c}{$ m_b = 205.7$}  \\

\midrule Masse d'eau ($m_e$) & $(g)$ &$ m_e1 = m_{tot} - m_b$ & $374.9$ & & $234.9$ & & $254$  \\

\thead Volume ($V$) & $(mm^3)$ &$ V_1$ & $374900$ &$ V_2$ & $243900$ &$ V_3$& $254000$ \\

\midrule Temps ($t$) & $(s)$ &$ t_1$ & $1120$ &$ t_2$ & $614$ &$ t_3$& $579$ \\

\midrule Débit ($Q$) & $Q(mm^3)=V/t$ &$ Q_1$ & $334.73$ &$ Q_2$ & $397.23$ & $ Q_3$& $438.68$ \\

\midrule Gradient hydraulique $i$ & $i=\dfrac{\delta H}{h} $ &$ i_1$ & $7.05$ &$ i_2$ & $8.29$ & $ i_3$& $9.07$ \\

\midrule Coefficient de perméabilité ($k(m/s)$)  & $k=Q/(S\ast i)$ \ref{EqC1}& $ k_1$ & $5.86\ast 10^{-6}$ & $ k_2$ & $5.91\ast 10^{-6}$ & $ k_3$& $5.97\ast 10^{-6}$  \\ 

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

This pic show the original table that I want to make by latex.

[image]
And this what i get with latex program :
[image]

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable by adding the document class you use? Giving advise on how to make your table fit into the textwidth is a ot easier with the information since the actual size of the textblock varies among different document calsses. Do you use the `geometry` package in your document? If so, please also include its settings in your example code.

Comment: The line starting with "Paramètre & Unité"  differs from the screenshot of the desired output. Which output do you actually want? The one from the code with "Gradient hydraulique"  before every "N." or the ne shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @leandriis thank you for your response i agree with you about this line, cause i change its forme. As you can see in the  desired output (the seconde pic) i want just to return to a newline in the "grandeur hydraulique N1" . same for "grandeur hydraulique N2"

Comment: Please if I could share my thesis by email, for a first vision of the form; I will need your point of view as an expert to improve the layout.

Comment: What is you document class and the general layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, here's a solution which builds on [@zarko's fine answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528516/5001).

IMNSHO, the table that the OP wishes to replicate somehow in LaTeX contains a lot of near-redundant information. Worse still, three of the six data columns do little except create visual clutter; simply omitting these three columns seems like a worthwhile idea.

The resulting table, shown below, admittedly doesn't bear much of a resemblance to the one in the OP's screenshot. That is, of course, the whole purpose of this exercise. I daresay that the result is a lot easier to read -- and hence also of more value to anyone who is actually *supposed to* to glean some presumably important pieces of information from the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand\tot{\mathrm{tot}}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{per-mode=symbol,tight-spacing,group-digits=false}
    \newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Essai de perméabilité sous charge constante}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l s T{4.2e-1} T{3.2e-1} T{4.2e-1} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{15cm}@{}}{\raggedright Paramètres du perméamètre type \textit{PROCTOR} --- 
Epaisseur: \SI{116.30}{\milli\metre}; Surface:~\SI{8107.32}{\milli\metre\squared};
Volume: \SI{942 881.28}{\milli\metre\cubed};  Diamètre: \SI{101.30}{\milli\metre}.}\\
\midrule
Paramètre & \mbox{Unité} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Gradient hydraulique} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-5}
& & {N. 1} & {N. 2} & {N. 3} \\
\midrule
Différence de hauteur ($\Delta H$) & \milli\metre & 820 & 965  & 1055 \\
Masse bécher et eau ($m_{\tot}$) & \gram & 580.6 & 449.6 & 459.7 \\
Masse bécher ($m_b$) & \gram  &  205.7 & 205.7 & 205.7  \\
Masse d'eau ($m_e=m_{\tot} - m_b$) & \gram & 374.9 & 234.9 & 254.0 \\
Volume ($V$) & \centi\metre\cubed & 374.9 & 243.9 & 254.0   \\
\addlinespace 
Temps ($t$) & \second & 1120 & 614 & 579 \\
Débit ($Q=V/t$) & \milli\metre\cubed\per\second & 334.73 & 397.23 & 438.68    \\
\addlinespace 
Gradient hydraulique ($i=\Delta H/t$) & \milli\metre\per\hour & 7.05 & 8.29 & 9.07 \\
Coefficient de perméabilité ($k=Q/(I\cdot S)$) & \metre\per\second & 5.86e-6 & 5.91e-6 & 5.97e-6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Small changes, big improvement :-) +1!

Comment: Thanks mico and Zarko , Please if I could send you my latex thesis by email, for a first view of the form; I will need your point of view as an expert to improve the layout of my thesis. thanks

Comment: @A.BOUZIANE - I'm not sure how much I could contribute as a proof reader. My main recommendation is that you focus on (a) keeping track of what your main messages are and (b) making sure that you express these ideas clearly and prominently. Conversely, spend as little time as needed on everything else. Another recommendation (due originally, I believe, to Greg Mankiw, a Harvard economics professor): "Put everything that's not essential into footnotes, not the main body of the document. Then delete all the footnotes." It's very very good advice, by the way!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you like the following tweaks to your table:

[image]

Since you did not provide any information about your document layout, I defined my own, as follows:

- text margin is defined to be 25mm (with use of the `geometry` package)
- used `article` document class and `babel` package with `french` option
- for units and columns with numbers only is used `siunitx` package
- multi line cell for common data of table is used `makecell` command from the package of the same name
- for making columns narrower are (two) equation cut of and marked with `\tnote` from `threeparttable` package (you can omit this, if you set table in landscape orientation)
- for shorter code is defined new command `mcc` (by use of `xparse` package)
- some indices are reformatted (maybe wrong because my guessing was wrong)
- corrected is font shape for units (they should be upright, not italic!)

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
        \newcommand\tot{\mathrm{tot}}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{booktabs, collcell, makecell, tabularx, threeparttable}
        \newcommand{\tclr}[1]{\textcolor{blue!70!black}{#1}}
        \newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\tclr\raggedright}X<{\endcollectcell}}

        \renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\bfseries} % optional
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \usepackage{xparse}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
        {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}


    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}
        \small
        \sisetup{table-format=6.2e-1,
                 per-mode=symbol,
                 tight-spacing}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}
    \caption{Essai de perméabilité sous charge constante}
    \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
                                L 
                                l   
                                *{3}{>{$}l<{$} S}
                                @{}}
    \toprule
    \mcc[8]{\makecell{Paramètres du perméamètre type \textit{PROCTOR}\\  
              Epaisseur: \SI{116.30}{\milli\metre}; 
              Surface: \SI{8107.32}{\milli\metre};
              Volume: \SI{942 881.28}{\milli\metre\cubed};
              Diamètres: \SI{101.30}{\milli\metre}   }
            }\\
    \midrule 
    Paramètre & Unité & \mcc[6]{Gradient hydraulique} \\
        \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-8}
    & & \mcc[2]{N. 1} & \mcc[2]{N. 2} & \mcc[2]{N. 3} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-6}  \cmidrule(l){7-8}
    Différence de hauteur ($\delta H$) 
        & \si{\milli\metre} 
        & \delta H_1 & 820      & \delta H_2 & 965      & \delta H_3    & 1055 \\
        \midrule 
    Masse bécher et eau ($m_{\tot}$) 
        & \si{\gram}  
        & m_{\tot_1} & 580.6    & m_{\tot_2} & 449.6    & m_{\tot_3}    & 459.7 \\
        \midrule 
    Masse bécher ($m_b$) 
        & \si{\gram}          &  \mcc[6]{$m_b = 205.7$}  \\
        \midrule 
    Masse d'eau ($m_e$)\tnote{a}%=m_{tot} - m_b 
        & \si{\gram}
        & m_{e_1}
                     & 374.9    &            &  234.9   &               &  254      \\
        \midrule
    Volume ($V$) 
        & \si{\milli\metre\cubed}  
        & V_1       & 374900    & V_2       & 243900    & V_3           & 254000   \\
        \midrule 
    Temps ($t$)     
        & \si{\second}
        & t_1       & 1120      & t_2       & 614       & t_3           & 579       \\
        \midrule 
    Débit ($Q=V/t$)
        & \si{\milli\metre\cubed\per\second}
        & Q_1       & 334.73    & Q_2       & 397.23    & Q_3           & 438.68    \\
        \midrule 
    Gradient hydraulique ($i$) 
        & $\delta H/h$ 
        & i_1       & 7.05      & i_2       & 8.29      & i_3           & 9.07      \\
        \midrule 
    Coefficient de perméabilité ($k$)\tnote{b} %=Q/(S\ast i)$ \ref{EqC1} 
        & \si{\metre\per\second}
        & k_1       & 5.86e-6  & k_2        & 5.91e-6   & k_3           & 5.97e-6 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

    \smallskip
    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
    \item[a] $m_{e}=m_{\tot} - m_b$
    \item[b] $k=Q/(S\cdot i)$ \ref{EqC1}
    \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
        \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I think, though, that you need `\milli\metre\cubed` rather than `\milli\metre\cubic` in a couple of places.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! Now I wonder that I didn't receive warning for this. Corrected and added text color to the first column.

Comment: You're most welcome! :-) I've permitted myself to apply a few additional tweaks, such as fixing the spelling of two words. (They were spelled incorrectly by the OP; e.g, Paramèmtres to Paramètres...)

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! Now answer is more complete and appealing.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I especially thank @Zarko for his answer and the corrections he was able to add to the results in the table.

Please if I could send you my latex thesis by email, for a first view of the form; I will need your point of view as an expert to improve the layout.

Comment: @Zarko, i am waiting for your response

Comment: Thank you dear Zarko. please find here my e-mail : abdelkhalek.bouziane@ced.uca.ma .